# Одна шапка для всех запросов mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас такой код

```html
<body>
<?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
 printf("<div class=\"resultat\"><table>
    <tbody><tr><th>Город:</th><th>Компания:</th><th>Телефон:</th><th>Категория:</th><th>Дата:</th></tr>   
 
<tr>
<td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['last_name'] ."</td>
<td>" .$row['email'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['facebook'] . "</td>
<td>" .$row['time'] . "</td>
</tr>

    </tbody></table></div>"
 );
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));


?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы шапка была одна, а остальное таблицей

Comment: Печатать шапку перед циклом а не внутри

Comment: А, если в бд нет данных, шапка все равно показывается

Comment: но вы же перед циклом fetch уже сделали, печатайте шапку если в $row есть данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
<?php
require 'scripts/connect.php';

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$table = "";
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

    $table .= "<div class=\"resultat\">
                <table>
                <thead><tr><th>Город:</th><th>Компания:</th><th>Телефон:</th><th>Категория:</th><th>Дата:</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody>";
    do
    {
        $table .= "
            <tr>
            <td>" .$row['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" .$row['last_name'] ."</td>
            <td>" .$row['email'] . "</td>
            <td>" .$row['facebook'] . "</td>
            <td>" .$row['time'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    $table .="</tbody></table></div>";

}
echo $table;
?>
```

P.S.:

1. Засовывать html в php плохая практика.
2. Расширение [mysql устарело и не поддерживается в новых версиях php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php).
3. В Вашем коде заголовки таблицы(шапка) обернуты в `tbody`, а по правилам должны в `thead`.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_nun_rows() in

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков опечатка, должно быть mysql_nu**m**_rows (функция возвращает количество строк), поправили. И не `mysql_num_rows($row)`, а `mysql_num_rows($result)`.

Comment: Еще одна ошибка Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Comment: @ВиталийНосиков уже исправлено, `mysql_num_rows($result)`